# Junit Mock JDBC Repository in Apache Camel

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, mockito

I am trying to mock the jdbc repository in camel but it is still calling the db calls without mocking.Please help me to correct it.

**Route:**

```
@Component
public class Router10 extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file:src/main/resources/in?delete=true").routeId("route1").process((exchange) -> {
            List<Customer> names = repository.findAll();
            System.out.println("names:"+names.size());
            exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
        }).split(simple("${body}")).to("direct:process1");

        from("direct:process1").routeId("process1").process((exchange) -> {
            exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(Customer.class).toString());
        }).to("file:src/main/resources/out?fileName=test_out.txt&fileExist=Append");

    }
}
```

**JUnit:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@SpringBootTest(classes = Router10.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RouterTest2 extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    public CustomerRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
         List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
         list.add(new Customer("F1","L1"));
         list.add(new Customer("F2","L2"));
        Mockito.when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(list);
    }


    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        File outDir = new File("src/main/resources/out");
        Assert.assertTrue(outDir.isDirectory());
    }    
}
```

Comment: don't you think you should add @MockBean to mock

Comment: @Sha_Coder for repo or Customer, thanks for reply.

Comment: Read about advice-with, and how you can replace or take out parts of your routes during testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple JavaBean class and replace the inline processor in your route with it. From there you can simply mock the real bean.